# VBA to add data and export as excel for a list

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a list of data that needs to be pasted in a form in next tab and export it into PDF

```
Sub Mpolicy()

Dim varItemsToReplace As Variant
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim wksDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngSource2 As Range
Dim rngCell As Range

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Instruction")
Set wksDest = Worksheets("Mobile Policy")

With wksSource
    Set rngSource = .Range("A5:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

For Each rngCell In rngSource
    With wksDest
    
    Range("A75").Formula = "=Instruction!A5"
    Range("C75").Formula = "=Instruction!C5"
    Range("E75").Formula = "=Instruction!B5"
    Range("G75").Formula = "=Instruction!D5"
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
    wksDest.Activate
         
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
         "C:\Users\jkurlawala\Desktop\Master Data Template\Joby Declaration\" & ActiveSheet.Range("A75").Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("C75").Value & ".pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
         :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


         
    End With
Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Unfortunately only 1 line of data is being copied from the list to policy form , rest of the list is not working

enter image description here[image: List]

[image: policy]

Comment: You never use `rngCell`  in your loop.

Comment: Your code repeats as many time as how many cells exist in the range **the same thing** (using row 75). Please, try explaining **in words** what you want doing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are trying to make a PDF for each record of the contiguous data on the sheet named "Instruction."  To do that you need to put the data from one row at a time onto the sheet called "Mobile Policy," which has the policy information common to each customer.  Then make a pdf of the policy with the customer data, naming according to the user's name and mobile model.  If so, here is a block of code that has been simplified to accomplish just that.  I've added comments to help you understand what each part is doing.

```
Sub Mpolicy()

    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim exportPath As String
    Dim exportRange As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    
    Set wksSource = Worksheets("Instruction")
    Set wksDest = Worksheets("Mobile Policy")
    
    'set the range of data to export to the block of contiguous data
    'starts in cell A5 of the source worksheet
    Set exportRange = wksSource.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
    
    'iterate over the sourece data, skipping the header row
    For x = 2 To exportRange.Rows.Count
        'copy data from the current user to the policy sheet     
        exportRange.Rows(x).Copy
        wksDest.Range("A75").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        
        'compose the full path for the current file to export, starting
        'with the path entered in cell B1 of the source worksheet
        exportPath = wksSource.Range("b1").Value & _
             wksDest.Range("A75").Value & " - " & _
             wksDest.Range("C75").Value & ".pdf"
             
        'make the PDF for the current row
        wksDest.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            filename:=exportPath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Gove , dont know why this does not work

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what line causes it?